# What class/type is undefined, and is it possible to extend / add a method to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, undefined, extend

I have a hash 'h' and have code like:

```
h[key].dostuff()
```

When the key does not exist in the hash, h[key] is undefined and I get an error saying I can't call method 'dostuff' of undefined.

Is there anyway to add this method to undefined, if undefined is an extendable class?

I'm sure this must be a common case so is there a preferred way of handling this without resorting to a workaround function, e.g. hh(key) in which I could manipulate undefined results?

Thanks.

Comment: To be `undefined` is to be, quite literally, undefined.  It means there's no value and nowhere to *find* a value. In this case, it means that there's no property on your "h" object whose name is the value of "key". (*edit* actually `undefined` can also be the "value" of a variable that's not initialized; JavaScript distinguishes that situation from a variable being `null`, which is a little strange.)

Comment: `h[key] && h[key].dostuff()` ???

Comment: Thanks all.  Was hoping undefined would belong to an extendable class, similar to nil and NilClass in ruby which is extendable.

Ah well.

Answer (score 2):

Since `undefined` is equated to `false` in javascript, you can combine the value check and function call, like this:

```
h[key] && h[key].dostuff();
```

This ensures that if `h[key]` has a value, `dostuff()` is called.

Comment: I see why it would be a better alternative than using a "normal" `if` statement, but I prefer readability and I'd go with it. I'm quite disturbed to see a logical value disappear like this in the abyss of the interpreter.

Comment: `I'm quite disturbed to see a logical value disappear like this in the abyss of the interpreter.` Ha! Welcome to data types in Javascript :D It really is down to personal preference whether you use this method or a standard `if` condition. I prefer this one for brevity.

Comment: My teamlead punishes me if i write If condition for single statement, he also prefers && =D

Answer (score 1):

```
if( h[key])
    h[key].dostuff()
```

this is a check "if value exist, doStuff()"

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like this:

```
h.get = function(key) {
    if(this.hasOwnProperty(key))
        return this[key];

    //here return a default object, whatever that would be
    return {doStuff: function() {
        //default doStuff function
    }};
};

h.get(key).doStuff();
```

I know it's a little forced solution, but it can somehow imitate the default behavior.